# Display user choice from list

Tags: python, list, user-input

Hi I'm writing a program currently I'm pretty new to python,

what I'm wanting is for the user to select from two options like so

```
1. Easy Mode
2. Hard Mode
```

Comment: Hint: Where do you define the variable for `choice`, and where do you re-set the variable after the user chooses? What are you printing? Also, what does `def(role)` do? As it stands, this code will give a syntax error if you try to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `Choice = int(...)`, so `Choice` is still `1` or `2`, so when you print it it'll show up as `1` or `2`. Instead, you could set a variable `mode` depending on which `if` statement is entered:

```
Choice = int(input("Select your difficulty: "))
mode = "Invalid choice" # Set a default value

if (Choice == 1):
  mode = "Easy Mode"
elif (Choice == 2):
  mode = "Hard Mode"

print ("Role: " , mode)
```

Of course, this doesn't account for the case when the user's input isn't one of these choices, but that's a different question: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/843953)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to associate the string the user enters with the one you want to display to them later:

```
difficulty = {
    "1": "Easy Mode",
    "2": "Hard Mode",
}

for c, desc in difficulty.items():
    print(f"{c}. {desc}")

choice = input("Select your difficulty: ")
while choice not in difficulty:
    choice = input(f"Choose one of: {', '.join(difficulty)}: ")

print(f"Role: {difficulty[choice]}")
```

```
1. Easy Mode
2. Hard Mode
Select your difficulty: asdf
Choose one of: 1, 2: 2
Role: Hard Mode
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I didn't think to use dictionary, I need to research on this for sure, thank you again